# Django query scope

Tags: python, django, laravel

Is there anything similar to [Laravel's Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) in [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)?

If not, how can one implement one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a custom manager/queryset, and define methods there that perform the desired operations on the queryset. Since querysets are lazy, that gives you the desired behaviour.

Take a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/

Comment: Link broken - new link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/ - Newer version (with better syntax!)